# Mail text encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I have a litle problem with my text encoding, when user filed textarea field with incoming  information by mail `(copy&paste)` like that `Also – can you give me some...` or `line item – QA coverage` and submited it, in my $_POST veriable text looks like `line item вЂ“ QA` , `Also вЂ“ can you give me some...` my site collatation is latin1_swedish_ci.

Any body know, how avoid this?
Thanks.
Best regards, Anton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `–` is the en-dash (not your typical `-` "minus"), which is a three-byte character in UTF-8. If its display screws up, it means you're not handling UTF-8 correctly, or more generally, you're not handling encodings correctly. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for a complete introduction.

Comment: my charset is ISO-8859-1, can i convert UTF-8 text to my current charset?

Comment: Yes, with [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv). Unless you have a really good reason for choosing ISO-8859 though, I'd suggest you take the opportunity to understand UTF-8 and use it, since your users seem to be using it occasionally.

Comment: Yeap the reasons exist,Thanks for help.